# TCL_LINK_STRING causing segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, multithreading, tcl

I'm trying to share a variable with c and tcl, the problem is when i try to read the variable in the c thread from tcl, it causes segmentation error, i'm not sure this is the right way to do it, but it seems to work for ints. The part that is causing the segmentation fault is this line is when i try to print "Var" but i want to read the variable to do the corresponding action when the variable changes.

Here is the C code that i'm using

```
void mode_service(ClientData clientData) {

while(1) {
    char* Var = (char *) clientData;
    printf("%s\n", Var);

    usleep(100000); //100ms
 }
}


static int mode_thread(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]) {
Tcl_ThreadId id;    
ClientData limitData;

limitData = cdata;
id = 0;
Tcl_CreateThread(&id, mode_service, limitData, TCL_THREAD_STACK_DEFAULT, TCL_THREAD_NOFLAGS);
printf("Tcl_CreateThread id = %d\n", (int) id);

// Wait thread process, before returning to TCL prog
int i, aa;
for (i=0 ; i<100000; i++) {aa = i;}

// Return thread ID to tcl prog to allow mutex use
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewIntObj((int)id));
printf("returning\n");
return TCL_OK;  
}


int DLLEXPORT Modemanager_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp){
if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL) {
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "PCIe", "1.0") == TCL_ERROR) {
    return TCL_ERROR;
}

// Create global Var
int *sharedPtr=NULL;
//sharedPtr = sharedPtr = (char *) Tcl_Alloc(sizeof(char));
Tcl_LinkVar(interp, "mode", (char *) &sharedPtr, TCL_LINK_STRING);


Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "mode_thread", mode_thread, sharedPtr, NULL);
return TCL_OK;
}
```

In the tcl code, i'm changing the variable mode whenever the user presses a button for example:

```
set mode "Idle"
button .startSamp -text "Sample Start" -width 9 -height 3 -background $btnColor -relief flat -state normal -command {set mode "Sampling"}
set threadId [mode_thread]
puts "Created thread $threadId, waiting"
```

Comment: How is `ClientData` defined?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey It's a `typedef` for `void*` (dating back to prior to `void*` being commonly available in compilers!) and _usually_ conveys a promise that Tcl won't look at the pointer and will instead just ship it around.

Comment: I'm temped to rename this question to "`printf("%s", NULL)` crashes my program"

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a complete mess! You need to decide what you are doing and then do just that. In particular, you are using `Tcl_LinkVar` so you need to decide what sort of variable you are linking to. If you get a mismatch between the storage, the C access pattern and the declared semantic type, you'll get crashes.

Because your code is in too complicated a mess for me to figure out exactly what you want to do, I'll illustrate with less closely related examples. You'll need to figure out from them how to change things in your code to get the result you need.

### Linking Integer Variables

Let's do the simple case: a *global* `int` variable (declared *outside* any function).

```
int sharedVal;
```

You want your C code to read that variable and get the value. Easy! Just read it as it is in scope. You also want Tcl code to be able to write to that variable. Easy! In the package initialization function, put this:

```
Tcl_LinkVar(interp              /* == the Tcl interpreter context */,
            "sharedVal"         /* == the Tcl name */,
            (char *) &sharedVal /* == pointer to C variable */,
            TCL_LINK_INT        /* == what is it! An integer */);
```

Note that after that (until you `Tcl_UnlinkVar`) whenever Tcl code reads from the Tcl variable, the current value will be fetched from the C variable and converted.

If you want that variable to be on the heap, you then do:

```
int *sharedValPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

C code accesses using `*sharedValPtr`, and you bind to Tcl with:

```
Tcl_LinkVar(interp                /* == the Tcl interpreter context */,
            "sharedVal"           /* == the Tcl name */,
            (char *) sharedValPtr /* == pointer to C variable */,
            TCL_LINK_INT          /* == what is it! An integer */);
```

### Linking String Variables

There's a bunch of other semantic types as well as `TCL_LINK_INT` (see the documentation for a list) but they all follow that pattern *except* for `TCL_LINK_STRING`. With that, you do:

```
char *sharedStr = NULL;
```

```
Tcl_LinkVar(interp, "sharedStr", (char *) &sharedStr, TCL_LINK_STRING);
```

You also need to be aware that the string will always be allocated with `Tcl_Alloc` (which is substantially faster than most system memory allocators for typical Tcl memory usage patterns) and not with any other memory allocator, and so will *also* always be deallocated with `Tcl_Free`.  Practically, that means if you set the string from the C side, you *must* use `Tcl_Alloc` to allocate the memory.

### Posting Update Notifications

The final piece to note is when you set the variable from the C side but want Tcl to notice that the change has set (e.g., because a `trace` has been set or because you've surfaced the value in a Tk GUI), you should do `Tcl_UpdateLinkedVar` to let Tcl know that a change has happened that it should pay attention to. If you never use traces (or Tk GUIs, or the `vwait` command) to watch the variable for updates, you can ignore this API call.

Comment: the only thing i want to do is read the tcl variable "mode" from the mode_service function in C once I'm able to read the variable as soon as it changes, i'll execute instructions accordingly to what the value of "mode" is. I'm sorry if the code is a mess i'm fairly new to the tcl/c programming, and this is just a proof of concept

Answer (score 1):

Donal's answer is correct, but I try to show you what you did with your ClientData.

To clarify: All (or almost all, Idk) Tcl functions that take a function pointer also take a parameter of type `ClientData` that is passed to your function when Tcl calls it.

Let's take a look at this line:

```
Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "mode_thread", mode_thread, NULL, NULL);
// ------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

You always pass `NULL` as `ClientData` to the `mode_thread` function.
In the `mode_thread` function you use the passed `ClientData` (`NULL`) to pass it as ClientData to the new Thread:

```
limitData = cdata;
// ...
Tcl_CreateThread(&id, mode_service, limitData, TCL_THREAD_STACK_DEFAULT, TCL_THREAD_NOFLAGS);
```

In the `mode_service` function you use the `ClientData` (which is still `NULL`)  as pointer to a `char` array:

```
char* Var = (char *) clientData;
```

Which is a pointer to the address `0x00`.
And then you tell `printf` to dereference this NULL pointer:

```
printf("%s\n", Var);
```

Which obviously crashes your program.

Comment: I'm fairly new to the hybrid programming with tcl, so i'm supposed to pass a ClientData variable when calling the Tcl_CreateObjCommand to be able to read the addr of the variable in mode_service.?

Comment: ClientData can be whatever you like. It is just passed around by Tcl. Do with it what you want, or you can ignore it. It's up to you (If you need the ClientData, you'll be glad it is there, and it is not the other way around)